# установка ядра linux-6.7.8

Tags: ubuntu

всем привет. у меня получилась ошибка при запуске make modules_install. скажите пожалуйста, как могу это исправить?

- SSL error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported: ../crypto/encode_decode/decoder_lib.c:101
  sign-file: ./
  make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modinst:121: /lib/modules/6.7.8/kernel/arch/x86/events/amd/amd-uncore.ko] Ошибка 1
  make[2]: *** Удаляется файл «/lib/modules/6.7.8/kernel/arch/x86/events/amd/amd-uncore.ko»
  make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-6.7.8/Makefile:1819: modules_install] Ошибка 2
  make: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Ошибка 2